# Is it possible to use IN1307N without oscillator?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I am planning to use the Integral IN1307 (RTC) IC as non volatile SRAM as it has power backup facility. I don’t want to use RTC at all, so is it possible to use that IC just as RAM without attaching a crystal oscillator?

Datasheet is [here](http://integral.by/sites/default/files/pdf/in1307e.pdf).

Comment: Do you have a battery on your system anyway or would it be there simply for RAM back up? If the latter, I suspect FRAM would be a better bet here.

Comment: Do you already have this device? If not there are serial SRAMs available with more memory for less money.

Comment: @DiBosco i am planning to put on 3vbattery just for in1307n to retain my data in case of power failures.

Comment: @Colin__s please suggest some SRAM IC with power backup circuit. i just need to hold 18 bytes only.    thank you

Comment: In which case I would advise using an FRAM such as this: http://www.cypress.com/file/136466/download then you won't need a battery.

Comment: @DiBosco I cost 110 INR for a piece and IN1307N will cost 25 INR. And the cost is considered as an issue because I am thinking about mass production once it gets stable.

Comment: How much does a battery cost?

Comment: @DiBosco 20 INR a piece

Comment: I have to say, I find those prices hard to believe. Also, it's much greener to not have a battery and you don't have to have the poor end user potentially having to change it.

Comment: @DiBosco they are right prices. if you ever need that in abundance let me know via e-mail i can get that for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the datasheet but looking at some other devices the I2C engine does not need an additional internal clock so the chip should work without a crystal oscillator. The low speed timing is caused by the low power usage requirements.